# How to return from function if multiple animations are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation

I´m using a function for which will animate some things, for example:

```
function doMyStuff(){
 $('#test1').animate({...}, {queue:false});
 $('#test2').animate({...}, {queue:false});
 return true;
}
// this should only go on if doMyStuff() is complete
doMyStuff();
alert("We can go on, doMyStuff() is finished");
```

I only want to go on, if this function is finished with his animation. How can I do this? Currently it doesn´t wait for the end of the animation.

Answer (score 4):

Make use of [promises](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/):

```
function doMyStuff(){
   return $.when(
     $('#test1').animate({...}, {queue:false}).promise(),
     $('#test2').animate({...}, {queue:false}).promise()
   );
}

doMyStuff().then(function() {
    alert("We can go on, doMyStuff() is finished");
});
```

All the code you want to execute after the animations finished has to be invoked from the callback that is passed to `.then`.

From the [`.promise` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) (emphasis mine):

> The `.promise()` method returns a dynamically generated `Promise` that is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have ended.
>
> By default, type is `"fx"`, which means **the returned `Promise` is resolved when all animations of the selected elements have completed**.

[`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) simply creates a new promise which is resolved when all promises passed to it are resolved.

Comment: Now i'm wondering why this work without using `.promise()`??? I mean: `return $.when(
     $('#test1').animate({...}, {queue:false}),
     $('#test2').animate({...}, {queue:false})
   );`

Comment: AFAIK, `$.when` calls `.promise()` if a jQuery object is passed as argument. But I like to be explicit :)

Comment: thank you very much! I only have one problem with this: I call "doMyStuff()" and this function calls also another function which will execute the animation. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5e3QG/ So how can I check the finish now?

Comment: @user3292653: You have to return the promise from `doMyStuff` :`return animateMe();`.